# store id and transfer to another php page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a little question.
On my site i use for few jquery functions , they get some data and transfer by GET method to php helper. This is not work when i want to use the data in another php page. For example i have jquery that store id of the anchor:

```
$("#rightContent .users_list li a").live('click', function() {

   var id = $(this).attr('id');

   $.get("getHelper",{'userId':id},function(data){

   $('#user_rightContent').html(data);
   });
});
```

And in php file returned by "getHelper" i do:

```
if(isset($_GET['userId'])){

    $id = $_GET['userId'];
        //do something  
);
```

The anchor of the live click lead to another page displayed by another php file where i want to use this id by using helper... This is work only if i stay on same page...
Can anybody help me in this problem?
thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

add return false at the end of live('click'....

```
live('click', function()
{
    // code ...
    return false;
}
```

or do that

```
live('click', function(e)
{
    // code ...
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Hi Merianos.In this case i will stay on same page.And i want to open another page by clicking on anchor :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the extension on the filename.

Try it with:

```
$("#rightContent .users_list li a").live('click', function() {

   var id = $(this).attr('id');

   $.get("getHelper.php",{'userId':id},function(data){

   $('#user_rightContent').html(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: May you have right. But I don't know may he has describe his problem with a wrong way :?

Comment: Hi Wakerneo. The get helper is my method, this return helper.php and this live click is work only if i stay on same page

Comment: What language are you two speaking?